# Compare records from two tables and highlight Diferences

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with exactly the same columns

**Table A**

```
id   FLAG
1    Y
2    Y
3    N
4    N
```

**Table B**

```
id   FLAG
1    Y
2
3    N
4
```

I would like to write a select query in Oracle that will display all rows in Table A where the `FLAG` column is not the same as Table B but having matching ID's columns

The result should be as follows.

```
id   FLAG
2    Y
4    N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"all rows in Table A ... as Table B having matching ID's columns":

```
FROM a JOIN b USING (id)
```

"where the FLAG column is not the same":

```
WHERE a.flag != b.flag 
   OR (a.flag IS NULL AND b.flag IS NOT NULL)
   OR (b.flag IS NULL AND a.flag IS NOT NULL)
```

So, the query would be

```
SELECT id, a.flag
  FROM a JOIN b USING (id)
WHERE a.flag != b.flag 
   OR (a.flag IS NULL AND b.flag IS NOT NULL)
   OR (b.flag IS NULL AND a.flag IS NOT NULL)
```

The `WHERE`-condition is ugly but necessary to catch the cases where table b has a `NULL`-value, but a not, or the other way round...

Answer (score 2):

this one works in oralce.. since there are null in columns.it cannot be directly compared so need to use **NVL()** or equivalent function

```
select a1.* from table_a a1,table_b b 
where A1.id=B.id
and nvl(a1.flag,'y')<>nvl(b.flag,'y')
```

please refer this sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/241de/1

Answer (score 1):

This will do,

```
    select Table_A.id,Table_A.FLAG from 
Table_A join Table_b on Table_A.id=Table_b.id 
where Table_A.FLAG!=Table_b.FLAG 
or (Table_b.FLAG is null and table_a.flag is not null);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/241de/5)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLEA 
      INNER JOIN TABLEB
      ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
    WHERE TABLEA.Flag != TABLEB.FLAG
       OR TABLEB.FLAG IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cc94c/4)

Comment: Marc - This query returns no records

Answer (score 0):

1. What if a row is in TAble A and not in Table B? would you still want to display it?
   That would help you decide if you want to do an inner join or an outer join.

Assuming that is the case, you can get the details using..

```
select a.id, a.flag, b.flag
  from table_a a,
       table_b b
  where a.id = b.id(+)
```

Since you need rows where the flag is not equal..

```
select a.id, a.flag, b.flag
  from table_a a,
       table_b b
  where a.id = b.id(+)
    and a.flag <> b.flag
```

Also check if the flag can be null, in which case the query might need to change a little bit.

Comment: Rajesh - I want to select only those records where the ID's exist in both tables.

Comment: IN that case, the join would be a inner join. (a.id = b.id)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.id = b.ID AND
                a.FLAG = b.FLAG
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da4a1/4)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that you were joking :)
Oracle has special MINUS operator in such cases.
[Proof link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

So the answer is very short and simple

```
select id, flag from a
minus
select id, flag from b
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bcc5/1)

P.S. Sorry - or there have to be records with corresponding ID in table B?
Then see below

```
select id, flag from a where id in (select id from b)
minus
select id, flag from b
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bcc5/2)